# android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals

Tags: android, exception, media-player, surfaceview

I have activity with MediaPlayer. But lots of users don`t like it because of crashes with exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1333)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout(IWindowSession.java:634)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3751)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can not reproduce this bug on my device, but according to the user messages I am a bad developer:)) and this exception appear after few seconds when video playback starts. It is interesting that it keeps working even after Error report dialog was shown.

Looking for a reason in android source code I found that it happens after transaction using iBinder.

```
mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_relayout, _data, _reply, 0);
_reply.readException();
```

This code executed in performTraversalsMethod in ViewRootImpl using Runnable that scheduled in scheduleTraversals method. And it is hard to get context of execution of it. scheduleTraversals called in lots of methods (invalidate,handleScreenStateChange....).

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version is it running on, which versions is it crashing on, what are you sending to the service -- sounds as if it were unknown data -- could it be you've tested it with a newer Android version than that of those customers where it crashes? Wild guessing without further information.

Answer (score 0):

It happens becouse I use WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SCALED on my Surface.

But as we can see from android sources: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/com/android/server/wm/WindowManagerService.java#2756

```
 if (attrs != null) {
            if (win.mAttrs.type != attrs.type) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Window type can not be changed after the window is added.");
            }
            flagChanges = win.mAttrs.flags ^= attrs.flags;
            attrChanges = win.mAttrs.copyFrom(attrs);
        }

        //...


        final boolean scaledWindow =
            ((win.mAttrs.flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SCALED) != 0);

        if (scaledWindow) {
            // requested{Width|Height} Surface's physical size
            // attrs.{width|height} Size on screen
            win.mHScale = (attrs.width  != requestedWidth)  ?
                    (attrs.width  / (float)requestedWidth) : 1.0f;
            win.mVScale = (attrs.height != requestedHeight) ?
                    (attrs.height / (float)requestedHeight) : 1.0f;
        } else {
            win.mHScale = win.mVScale = 1;
        }
```

From first "if" we see that attr == null is a normal situation, but in the case of using 
scaledWindow this parameter is not checked for null. And as a result we have NullPointerException.

WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SCALED should not be used in any case.